# Finding not equal adjacent indexes in vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator

I have this vector of ints:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3};
```

and I want to find indexes, where the adjacent elements aren't equal:

```
1
4
5
```

My solution is (which isn't working):

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3};

auto i1 = std::begin(v);

while(1)
{
    i1 = std::adjacent_find(i1, std::end(v), std::not_equal_to<int>());
    std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(v), i1) << '\n';

    if (i1++ == std::end(v))
        break;
}
```

This prints:

```
1
4
6
```

The last elements points to index 6, but I want it to point 5 (value 3). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you describe in words exactly what "indexes, where the adjacent elements aren't equal" means to you?

Comment: @JohnZwinck values `1, 2` aren't equal, so index of last value `1` (that's 1). Then `2, 3` aren't equal, so index of last value `2` (that's 4). Then we have last value 3 left, so output this index too (that's 5). But yeah, maybe the formulation of problem isn't correct, as @marek-r stated..

Answer (score 2):

Your code and expected answer are invalid. Proper answer for this data is:

```
1
4
```

Last iteration of your loop treats result where nothing was found as a valid result.
That is why you see size of the array as a last result.

So fixed code looks like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3};

auto i1 = std::begin(v);

while(1)
{
    i1 = std::adjacent_find(i1, std::end(v), std::not_equal_to<int>());
    if (i1 == std::end(v))
        break;

    std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(v), i1) << '\n';
    ++i1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it will always treat the last index in this way, you could just subtract 1 from the last value in the otherwise correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach (I renamed `i1` to `it`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 };

    auto it = std::begin(v);

    do
    {
        it = std::adjacent_find( it, std::end(v), std::not_equal_to<int>());
        if ( it == std::end( v ) ) it = std::prev( it );

        std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(v), it) << '\n';

        std::advance( it, 1 );
    } while ( it  != std::end( v ) );        
}
```

The program output is

```
1
4
5
```

Before calling the do-while loop you should check that the vector is not empty.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 };

    if ( not v.empty() )
    {
        auto it = std::begin(v);

        do
        {
            it = std::adjacent_find( it, std::end(v), std::not_equal_to<int>());
            if ( it == std::end( v ) ) it = std::prev( it );

            std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(v), it) << '\n';

            std::advance( it, 1 );
        } while ( it  != std::end( v ) );
    }        
}
```

As for your approach then you are trying to output

```
std::distance(std::begin(v), std::end( v ) )
```

that is equal to `6` when `i1` is equal to `std::end( v )`.